# How prove this binomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, binomial-coefficients, real-numbers

this problem  from book,he say it is clear have$$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}(a+tk)^{n-j-1}(-1)^{n-k-j}(a+b)^j
=a^{-1}(a+b)^n$$ where $a.b$ be real numbers,

why it is clear? if not,how to prove it?

Comment: One way to proof this might be induction but this is not the best way I guess. Have you tried that?

Comment: Where did the $t$ dependency disappear to ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: the expression is not dependent on $t$.

Comment: @GuyFsone: you've said this in your answer and here in a comment. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}(a+tk)^{n-j-1}(-1)^{n-k-j}(a+b)^j\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}(a+tk)^{n-j-1}(-1)^{n-k-j}(a+b)^j\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}(a+tk)^{n-j-1}(-1)^{n-k-j}(a+b)^j\tag3\\
&=\underbrace{a^{-1}(a+b)^n\vphantom{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}}}_{j=n}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-j}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}\overbrace{(a+tk)^{n-j-1}}^{\substack{\text{degree $n-j-1$}\\\text{polynomial in $k$}}}(-1)^{n-k-j}}_{\text{$\Delta^{n-j}$ of a degree $n-j-1$ polynomial $=\ 0$}}(a+b)^j\tag4\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a^{-1}(a+b)^n}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: the sum in $j$ can be extended to $n$ since $\binom{n-k}{j}=0$ for $j\gt n-k$
$(3)$: $\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}=\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}$ (write them out in terms of factorials)
$\phantom{(3)\text{: }}$and switch order of summation
$(4)$: pull the $j=n$ term out in front of the sum
$\phantom{(4)\text{: }}$when $j=n$, $\binom{n-j}{k}=0$ if $k\ne0$ so the sum in $k$ is trivial
$(5)$: an $n-j$ order [repeated difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) of a degree $n-j-1$ polynomial is $0$

Comment: Hello, some of wrong? $\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}$,and three step I can't understand

Comment: @functionsug: the sum can be extended to $k=n$ since $\binom{n-j}{k}=0$ for $k\gt n-j$.

Comment: $\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}=\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}?$

Comment: It knew the justification in the second underbrace was required... & this would cause the $t$ dependency to disappear... I just could not quite get there ... so well done you Sir !

Comment: can you explain the last setp why is =0? and the three step why is equal?

Comment: @functionsug: I have detailed each step. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: For Mathematica: `f[n_, a_, b_, t_] := Sum[Binomial[n, n - k] Binomial[n - k, j]
   (a + t k)^(n - j - 1) (-1)^(n - k - j) (a + b)^j, {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, n - k}]` Setting $n,a,b$ and leaving $t$ variable shows that there is no dependence on $t$.